# Prolog rule within a rule

Tags: parameters, prolog, rules

I have a simple prolog program that is trying to determine who trusts who based of the trusts rule and the knows rule.  Here it is

```
know(joe,jack).
know(joe,sue).
know(joe,betty).
know(sue,betty).
know(jack,betty).
know(bill,betty).

knows(X,Y):- know(X,Y);know(Y,X).

trust(jack,joe).
trust(bill,joe).
trust(betty,jack).
```

The **knows** rule is symmetric and transitive,and the **trusts** rule is defined by

```
Person X trusts Y if and only if
-X inherently trusts Y, or
-X knows two DIFFERENT people who trust Y.
```

Trust is not symmetric and not transitive.

I am not sure how to do rules within rules, and the variables seem to be messing me up, as in trying to only have 2 variables as parameters but use 4 in the rule.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: For a start, only a small hint: To express that two terms are *different*, you can use the predicate `dif/2`. See [tag:prolog-dif] for more information. It's completely OK that only some of the variables you use in the rule body appear in the head. In fact, that is a rather typical case. The key is to think about it declaratively, i.e., describe the constraints that must hold for the arguments, using any additional variables you need.

Comment: @mat I have created this rule, but for some reason it is causing an infinite loop.  trusts(X,Y):- dif(A,B),knows(X,A),trusts(A,Y),knows(X,B),trusts(B,Y). Any idea why this would be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question somehow suggests that you think you *must* have in the head of a predicate all variables that appear in the body of a predicate. This is not necessary. Say I wanted to find the number people that someone in our problem definition knows:

```
?- bagof(X, knows(betty, X), Xs), length(Xs, N).
```

You maybe really just want to know that Betty knows 4 people, but the toplevel will write the list of people Betty knows anyway. So instead you put it in a predicate:

```
knows_count(X, N) :-
    bagof(Y, knows(X, Y), Ys),
    length(Ys, N).
```

So now you only see what you need to see:

```
?- knows_count(betty, N).
N = 4.

?- knows_count(X, N).
X = betty, N = 4 ;
X = bill,  N = 1 ;
X = jack,  N = 2 ;
X = joe,   N = 3 ;
X = sue,   N = 2.
```

You have now "hidden" the list of people in the body of `knows_count/2`.

To define the second case of `trusts/2`, you can do the same:

```
trusts(X, Y) :-
    knows(X, A), trust(A, Y), ... % and so on
```

As pointed out by @mat, now all you have to do is make sure that all the people whom "X knows" in the body of the predicate are not the same person. See the [link in the comment by @mat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog-dif) or just search Stackoverflow for [`[prolog] dif`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprolog%5D+dif).

Comment: I tried doing it this way and have made no progress.  No matter what I do I end up with an infinite loop because Prolog isn't smart enough to not loop back on itself.  I have tried to understand how your first example problem relates to the trust problem, but I can't figure that out either.

Comment: @Johnny The most important thing is: you need one clause of `trusts/2` which is not recursive, and is defined in terms of the fact `trust/2` only; the other clause will be defined in terms of `knows/2` and the fact `trust/2`, I guess. That, and use `dif/2` to make sure that variables that must be different are different.

Comment: @Johnny I noticed that I actually made a serious mistake (now edited!) in the small code snippet above: I used `trusts/2` instead of `trust/2`, so actually the predicate was recursively defined, even though you explicitly said in your question that "trust" in **not** a transitive relationship.... Sorry about wasting your time :-(

Comment: Sorry this is so late, but I think I got it, and I just wanted to make sure this makes sense. Trusts(X,Y):- dif(A,B),knows(X,A),trusts(A,Y),knows(X,B),trusts(B,Y).

Comment: This is what you are telling me to do, however this ends up in an infinite loop because I believe it loops back to the starting variable and is unable to conclude that it should stop there.

Comment: @Johnny You still have the same mistake that I made initially (again, I feel bad for misleading you on this). "Trusts" is not a transitive relationship; if you define `trusts` in terms of itself this makes it a transitive relationship. You **must** use `trust` (**no 's' at the end**) in the body of `trusts`. The definition **must be non-recursive** if the relationship is not transitive.

Comment: Ahh I finally see. I got it working now. trusts(X,Y):-knows(X,A),knows(X,B), A\=B, trust(A,Y), trust(B,Y). Thanks for your help!